# How do I pass additional params to dispatch()?

Tags: webapp2

An API I'm writing accepts two arguments via URL - e.g /api/targets/foo/bar

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/api/targets/(\w*?)/(\w*?)$', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

This fires off a GET handler:

```
def get(self, url_1, url_2):
    #do some stuff
```

The cool thing here is that I can reference url_1 (foo) and url_2 (bar) inside my GET handler and they're defined for me.

I have another page which accepts both GET and POST requests. About 90% of what happens is the same in either case, so I've opted to use def dispatch() instead of having two separate handlers.

The problem here is that (even though I still have the regex blocks enclosed in my webapp2.WSGIApplication initialisation) they are no longer passed to the request handler, so I have to define them like this:

```
    url_1= self.request.url.split("/")[3]
    url_2= self.request.url.split("/")[4]
```

Which makes me feel like a peon. If I tell dispatch() to expect those two params, they never arrive - what do I need to do to mimic the get behaviour in dispatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be shorter to use:

```
arg_one = self.request.route_args[0]
arg_two = self.request.route_args[1]
```

Take a look at the [webapp2 docs](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Request) for the Request object, specifically the `route_args` and `route_kwargs` towards the bottom of the Request section.

This is an interesting use case. If I were you, I would keep get() and post() separate. If get() and post() share code, then I would move that code to a method of the RequestHandler that can be called from both get() and post(), or move the shared code into another class (I find a lot of my RequestHandlers just call methods on my model classes).

If you still want one method to replace both get() and post(), then instead of using dispatch(), I recommend you set the `handler_method` for the Route (see [here in the docs](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#custom-methods)). I would advise against handling these requests entirely in the dispatch() method, as that is supposed to, at some point, call the "handler method", which defaults to GET/POST/etc. based on the HTTP method, but you can set your own handler method to handle GET and POST and whatever else.

If you set the `handler_method`, it would look like this:

```
# note that handler_method is the method name as a string
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/api/targets/(\w*?)/(\w*?)$', MainPage, handler_method='handle_request'),
], debug=True)
```

In your handler:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # note that your method signature MUST have args for the route args,
    # or else an exception will occur
    def handle_request(self, arg_one, arg_two):
        # your code here
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            # do GET stuff
        elif self.request.method == 'POST':
            # do POST stuff
```

This is nice because it leaves dispatch() unchanged. I like to think of dispatch() as pre- and post-processing to occur before/after calling get()/post()/whatever handler method you specify.

Comment: I'm not sure why this took me a month to notice, but perfect answer. Well explained, patient and constructive. Thank you so much :)